# Using a variable outside of definition in python

Tags: python, return, definition

I want to use val outside of definition,

```
def definition(var):

    list=["b","2","3"]

    val = list[var]
    return val

definition(0)
print(val)
```

but its giving this error:

```
  print(val)
NameError: name 'val' is not defined
```

Comment: `val = definition(0)`. Don't name your variable "list", it overrides the built-in "list" function.

Comment: why don't you update the suggestion first and get the working code for previous problem

Comment: Since `a()` does not return anything what are you expecting `d` to be in this line?
`for d in a("hour")`

Comment: Please don't completely change the question after people have provided answers

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you shouldn't use the `list` symbol, as it is a built-in Python function.

But what the issue here is, you aren't actually assigning `val` any value. As it is defined within the scope of that function, it cannot be access outside its closure.

So, you'd need to state `val = definition(0)` so that the return value of `definition` will be stored in `val`, within the right scope.

```
def definition(v):
    l = ["b","2","3"]

    return l[v]

value = definition(0)
print(value)
```

Comment: This answer still suffices. In order for a variable to exist, you need to declare it, and you need to do so within the proper scope. Otherwise, you should use the `global` keyword to instantiate a global variable, but that would break your script and is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to print the value of the list at the position given to the function. Below is one way:

```
def definition(var):

    mylist=["b","2","3"]

    val = mylist[var]
    return val

my_val = definition(0)
print(my_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with `jordanm` comment. `list` is a reserved keyword. Also, try to avoid using variable name `val` or `var`. It will create confusion.

```
def definition(var):

    listabc=["b","2","3"]

    val = listabc[var]
    return val

val = definition(0)
print(val)
```